# Glow around objects in AFM image (amplitude modulation mode)

Tags: experimental-physics, microscopy, imaging

I have made an AFM scan (Amplitude modulation mode) of a sample consisting of polyethylene in a matrix of polystyrene. I have tried to figure out why there appears a 'glow' around the domes of polyethylene. I am also interested in knowing why the dark edge appears on the left side of the image. The reason why it only appears on the left side is likely because the sample had a slight inclination, with the left side slightly higher than the right side.
Can anyone give an explanation of the glow and the dark edges?

[image]

Comment: If you change the scan conditions, do you know if the dark 'semicircle' stays aligned with the tilt direction or stays aligned with the scan axes?

Comment: @RogerWood, I would like to see that myself, but I am not able to redo the experiment for the moment.

Comment: Since in an AFM the tip interact with the surface under investigation, one has to consider possible effects of tip asymmetry.  That may be playing a role here.

Comment: @CGS, the glow is about 200 nm, which I believe is too much to be caused by tip asymmetry.